# Rewrite SQL query using Linq to entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq-to-entities

Hi guys I need to rewrite the sql query below using Linq to entity. Unfortunately I don't have a lot of experience of using Linq. Please help me

```
 With TempTableName AS 
(SELECT [ColumnName],  
        [ColumnName2], 
        [ColumnName3], 
        [ColumnName4], 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by ColumnName desc) as RowNumber from TableName )
         SELECT 
        [ColumnName],  
        [ColumnName2], 
        [ColumnName3], 
        [ColumnName4]
FROM TempTableName  WHERE ROWNUMBER 
Between 10 and 100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(from t in dbContext.TableName
order by ColumnName descending
select new { ColumnName = t.ColumnName, ColumnName2 = t.ColumnName2 /* ... */  })
.Skip(9)
.Take(91)
```

If you want to work all the columns from `TableName`, you can also use `select t`, this. Probably easier to use, but this will fetch all columns, and it is not clear from your question if that is what you want.